Find the image of the right half plane $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 $ under $w = i(1 - z)/(1 + z)$
I tried to replace $z$ in $x+iy$ and found:
$w=\frac{2y}{(1+x)^2+y^2}+i\frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{(1+x)^2+y^2}$, and I have no idea how to continue.
Furthermore, what is the main strategy to solve the problem as such?

Let $w=a+ib$ be in the image. Then we can recover $z$ in terms of $w$ as $z=\tfrac{1+iw}{1-iw}=\tfrac{1-a^2-b^2}{(1+b)^2+a^2}+\tfrac{2a}{(1+b)^2+a^2}i$.
So note that if we want $\Re(z)>0$, this just reduces to $a^2+b^2<1$. So the image is the inside of the unit disk.

Use identity:
$$|z_1-z_2|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2^2-2\rm{Re}(\overline{z_1}z_2)|,$$
$$|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2^2+2\rm{Re}(\overline{z_1}z_2)|$$
then
$$\left|i\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right|<1\iff|1-z|^2<|1+z|^2\\
\iff1+|z|^2-2\rm{Re}(z)<1+|z|^2+2\rm{Re}(z)
\iff \rm{Re}(z)>0.$$

This is easy if you know Möbius transformations permute generalized circles.
Check that $i,0,-i$ go to $1,i,-1$ respectively, and $1$ goes to $0.$
So the imaginary axis goes to the unit circle and the image is the unit disk.

If $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$, let $f(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$. Then$$|1+z|^2=1+2\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|^2\quad\text{and}\quad|1-z|^2=1-2\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|^2,$$and therefore\begin{align}|f(z)|^2&=\left|i\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right|^2\\&=\frac{1-2\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|^2}{1+2\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|^2}\\&<1.\end{align}So, the half-plane $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ is mapped into the open unit disk by $f$.
Now, if $z$ belongs to the open unit disk, let $g(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$. It is easy to check that, for each $z$ in the open unit disk, $f(g(z))=z$ (and that, for each $z$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$, $g(f(z))=z$). But then $f$ must map the half plane $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ onto the open unit disk: if $w$ belongs to the open unit disk, then $w=f(g(w))$.

Thank you professor!
